# REST-Assured - Unable to access a particular key in the JSON response

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

I'm using the REST-Assured library and I'm facing a very strange issue accessing a particular key `freshdeskId` in below JSON response, which is a `Response` object in my code.

```
{
    "status": true,
    "responseData": {
        "orderId": "553259",
        "orderItemName": "None",
        "userId": "636049",
        "freshdeskId": "#155",
        "orderItemId": null,
        "updatedOn": 1491824018000,
        "message": "OK"
    }
}
```

I'm able to access other fields like `orderId`, `userId`, `updatedOn`, etc. using `response.path("responseData.orderId")` (or similar), but `response.path("responseData.freshdeskId")` returns an empty string, whereas it is expected to return the "#155" value.

Comment: did you look at the response JSON itself in your network tab? it's possible that the server sent you an empty string.

Comment: @JoshuaJWilborn Thanks for the quick response. I tried dumping the output of `response.asString()` and found that the field `freshdeskId` indeed has an empty string (""). But if I hit the same API from Postman, I get a proper string value ("#155"). This looks strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the root cause for this issue, turns out this was a server side issue as it did not send the value for `freshdeskId` attribute since the same was required to be fetched **asynchronously** from somewhere else.

So as a solution, I added a wait of 60 seconds in my test which generates the `response`. The value is `freshdeskId` is updated in backend during this time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this? https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#bootstrapping-restassuredmockmvc

Also, the request to support async is added here - https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/462

Comment: No, I haven't. But how does it relate to my issue?